# Is it safe to truncate a rounded double?

Tags: .net, rounding, truncate

`Math.Round(myDouble)` returns a floating-point `double`, and as we all know, `double` has a limited amount of precision. So `Math.Round` could potentially return a value slightly larger *or* smaller than the true integer value that we seek.

If it returns a slightly larger value, it would be safe to cast the result to an `int`. For example:

```
Math.Round(19.5) -> 20.0000000000002 -> (int)20.0000000000002 -> 20
```

But if it returns a slightly smaller value, it would *not* be safe to cast the result to an `int`. For example:

```
Math.Round(19.5) -> 19.9999999999998 -> (int)19.9999999999998 -> 19
```

Is this correct reasoning? **Is it always unsafe to cast the result of `Math.Round` to an integer?**

Or in other words, would this...

```
public static int ConvertToInt(double val)
{
    return (int)Math.Round(val, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

... ever return a different value than this...

```
public static int ConvertToInt(double val)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(val, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
}
```

?

Comment: If you ask it to round to 0 digits after decimal separator, then double should be able to precisely represent the actual value, unless you have such a high value that you don't have enough digits available *in front of* the decimal separator to precisely represent it.

Comment: However, I could very well foresee that there *is* a certain double value that will evaluate to different ints using your two methods, considering the `Convert.ToInt32` [method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1087) seems to do some funky stuff regarding very high values. Whether this will actually be important to you or not is doubtful.

Comment: `double` can represent all values in `int` exactly, so your question boils down to "is the result of `Math.Round(val, 0)` always a precise integer" -- since if it is, the casting is safe, and if it's not, then the casting is not safe. That part is not specific to rounding. (But if `Round` couldn't produce integers "precise enough", why do you think `Convert` would?)

Comment: @JeroenMostert While I stand corrected, I'll at least answer why I _thought_ it might be better to use `Convert`: It doesn't simply truncate / cast. The method also has [rounding logic](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1092) to ensure you get the nearest `int` (not `double`). Though it uses Banker's rounding, not "AwayFromZero" rounding like in my sample.

Comment: `Convert` is weird and slow (for the general case where it transforms any type into any type) and its semantics often diverge from "obvious" behavior in the language. At least the behavior of `.ToInt32(Double)` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Double_), but it remains the case that it's not really useful as a yardstick of what other operations do. `Convert` is a sort of "do the right thing" class where it's often not immediately obvious what the authors *considered* "the right thing".